# Max possible number of executors in cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have `5` worker nodes in a cluster and each node has `48 cores` and `256 GB RAM`.

Then what are the maximum number of executors possible in the clusters?

will cluster have `5*48 = 240` executors or only 5 executors?

Or there are some other factors that will decide the number of executors in a cluster, then what are they?

Thanks.

Comment: I think each executor runs in it's own JVM, so as long as you have enough memory, you can spawn an executor. Tasks are more closely related t number of cores than executors. I might be wrong, inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The number of executors is related to the amount of parallelism your application need. You can create 5*48 executor with 1 core each, but there's others processes that should be considered, like memory overhead, cluster management process, scheduler, so you may need to reserve 2-5 cores/node to management processes.
I don't know what architecture your cluster use, but this article is a good start if you are using hadoop , https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html